# Combinatorics problem: Splitting 90 students into 3 classes

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A group of 90 students is to be split at random into 3 classes of equal size. All partitions are equally likely. Joe and Jane are members of the 90-student group. Find the probability that Joe and Jane end up in the same class.

Answer:
[image]

---

Another way of thinking of this:

The different ways of partitioning into 3 partitions, each of size 30 is:
`all = 90! / (30!)^3`

The number of ways in which Joe and Jane can be at the same class is:
`x = 88! / (30! * 30! * 28!)`

and since there are 3 classes, the answer is 3 times the above expression:
`y = 3 * x`

Final answer:
`y / all`

This way of thinking works.

---

Yet, another way:

We can consider both Joe and Jane to be 1 student, in other words, think of them as one unit, and consider the number of students to be 89, and the partitions to be 30, 30, and 29.

This way, the number of ways in which they would be together:

`z = 89! / (30! * 30! * 29!)`

and the final answer would be `z / all`.

Unfortunately, this is not true.

you can see that `z = x * 89/29 = x * 3.06896551724` which is not equal to `x * 3`.

What's wrong with the last logic?

Comment: Oh... this one unit can end up in a class with a size of 30, making the class containing 31 students.

Comment: yes you answered yourself

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with the last approach is that not all configurations are equally probable.  As we see in the others, the chance is less than $1/3$ because the first one you put in a class takes up one space, so there are fewer spaces left for the other.

Answer (score 1):

29/89 is the correct answer.  However the analysis is overly complicated.  Simple approach:  There are 29 students in the same class as Joe and 60 in the other classes.  Since Jane's class assignment is random, she has 29/89 chance of being in the same class as Joe.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked, which is what is wrong with the last argument.  Your answer to the original problem is correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan The last argument was too convoluted, but it appeared to be answered, so I ignored it.

Comment: The last argument began with "We can consider both Joe and Jane to be 1 student, ...", but we can not do that.

Comment: Not only does this answer not answer the actual question, but also, it is already present, with only slightly different wording, in the question.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am aware of the fact that the answer was in the question.  My point was that the analysis using binomial coefficients was unnecessarily complicated.  I offered a direct simpler approach.

Comment: The question: "I know you can make a pie with apples or with cherries. But can you make a pie with oranges?" Your answer: "I don't like apple pie, but you can make a pie with cherries."

Comment: @MishaLavrov I prefer the KISS principle.  Using your analogy, walking a half mile to get from A to B or hiring a limo.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever class Joe is in, there are 29 other students.  Jane can be selected to be one among these with a probability of $29/89$.

This may also be viewed as: there are $\binom 31\binom{30}2$ ways to select two *seats* in the same class, and $\binom{90}{2}$ ways to select two seats from anywhere among the three classes. So the probability for obtaining seats in the same class when selecting two from the ninety seats, without bias, for Joe and Jane is: $$\dfrac{3\cdot 30\cdot 29/2}{90\cdot 89/2}$$

---

> What is wrong with the last logic?
>
> > We can consider both Joe and Jane to be 1 student,

No.  We cannot.  If they were super-glued together, they would certainly be in the same class.